# Density of periodic points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Tags: dynamical-systems, diffeomorphism

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$, $d\geq 2$ be a diffeomorphism. Suppose that $\bigcup_{n\geq 0}f^n(U)=\mathbb{R}^d$ for any open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Questions:

1. Is it true then that the periodic points of $f$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}^d$? (Periodic points are points where $f\circ\dots\circ f=f^n(x)=x$ for some $n\geq 1$.)
2. What if $f$ is just differentiable?
3. If 1 is not true are there any other assumptions under which  it is true?

Any references are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by periodic points? Do you mean $x$ such that there exists $v_x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $f(x+m\cdot v)=f(x)$ for all $m\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur No, the OP means periodic for $f$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Can you clarify the definition of what you think he means then? I don't completely understand what periodicity is this supposed to be.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur $x$ is periodic if there exists $k \geq 1$ such that $f^k(x)=x$.

Comment: @MadMax Not really sure about what I am saying and if that helps (my dynamical systems are quite rusty !), but you can prove that under the given conditions on $f$, the non-wandering set is $\mathbb{R}^d$. And I think that for $\mathcal{C}^1-$generic diffeomorphisms, the set of periodic points is dense in the non-wandering set. This would give a sufficient condition, I guess.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Do you have a reference for the fact that periodic points are dense in the non-wandering set? I have never heard of this before.

Comment: @MadMax It is not true in general, but it is true for a generic set of diffeos : see for example http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Pugh_closing_lemma the paragraph "Generic density of the periodic orbits in the non-wandering set". All these things are related with hyperbolicity and axiom A.

Comment: Wouldn't something like $f(x,y) = (2x \cos(\sqrt{2}) - 2y \sin(\sqrt{2}), 2x \sin(\sqrt{2}) + 2y \cos(\sqrt{2}))$ give you a diffeo that satisfies the condition but has no periodic points beyond $(0,0)$? (I might be very wrong.)

Comment: @User203940 This is linear, so I think it has no chance to satisfy the condition (for example, how can you reach $0$ from a open set that does not contain $0$ ?) ! How did you prove that the condition is satisfied ?

Comment: Maybe that's where my confusion is at. I chose something which was expanding so that $\bigcup_{n \geq 0} f^n(U) = \mathbb{R}^2$ for any nontrivial open set $U$. So in fact an easier question is why doesn't $f(x,y) = (2x, 2y)$ just trivially satisfy being a diffeo so that $\bigcup_{n \geq 0} f^n(U) = \mathbb{R}^2$ for any nontrivial open $U$?

Comment: @User203940 Expanding does not mean that $\bigcup_{n \geq 0} f^n(U) = \mathbb{R}^2$. Just consider in $\mathbb{R}$ the application $x \mapsto 2x$. The image by $f^n$ of the open set $(1,2)$ for any $n\geq 0$ will always be included in $(1,+\infty)$, therefore you cannot reach the numbers that are $<1$. It would be correct if you asked the property for open sets **that contain** $0$, but the condition is that it must hold for every open set.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ah yes, okay that solves that issue. Thanks!